# img width 100% event

Tags: javascript, polymer

Click on the red square and see the console log output

How can I get rid of this `setTimeout 500` hack to get the correct 100% width of a image?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <title>Jsbin</title>

  <script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/transitions/cross-fade.html" rel="import">
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html" rel="import">
  <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/font-roboto/roboto.html">

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body unresolved>

  <polymer-element name="to-soon" attributes="activePage">
    <template>
      <img src="http://sea-is-snow.appspot.com/icon/loading.gif" style="width:100%">
      <span style="color:green; position:fixed; bottom:0px; right:0px; z-index:1;">TO SOON</span>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        activePageChanged: function() {
          if (this.activePage != 1) return 0
          console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('img').width)
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('img').width)
          }.bind(this), 500);
        },
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>


  <template is="auto-binding" unresolved>

    <core-drawer-panel rightDrawer>

      <core-header-panel main>
        <core-toolbar class="core-header">
          <select onchange="change();">
            <option value="cross-fade-all" selected>cross-fade-all</option>
            <option value="slide-from-right">slide-from-right</option>
          </select>
        </core-toolbar>
        <core-animated-pages selected={{activePage}} class="content" onclick="stuff();" transitions="cross-fade-all" fit relative>
          <section>
            <div layout vertical center center-justified style="background:red;" fit>1</div>
          </section>
          <section>
            <to-soon activePage={{activePage}}></to-soon>
          </section>
        </core-animated-pages>
      </core-header-panel>

      <core-header-panel drawer style="background:#eee; overflow:auto;">
        <core-toolbar class="core-header">Hello</core-toolbar>
        <div class="content">world</div>
      </core-header-panel>

    </core-drawer-panel>

  </template>

  <script>
    function change() {
      var s = document.querySelector('select');
      document.querySelector('core-animated-pages').transitions = document.querySelector('select').options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    }

    var up = true;
    var max = 1;

    function stuff() {
      var p = document.querySelector('core-animated-pages');
      if (up && p.selected === max || !up && p.selected === 0) {
        up = !up;
      }
      if (up) {
        p.selected += 1;
      } else {
        p.selected -= 1;
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And the question has been downvoted because?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Polymer({
    ready: function() {
      addEventListener('core-animated-pages-transition-end', function () {
        console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('img').width)
      }.bind(this));
    },
  });
```

the above function returns the correct width for me in this plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RGldJcDgn3TzlNIRg0n0?p=preview

Comment: Hmm ok going to test something because, I don't think that is the correct place to add a event listener?

Comment: You are correct, after setting it in the ready function it still works. Guess I miss spelled the event listener or something, thanks.

Comment: yes maybe not the best spot for the event listener. wasn't thinking best practices at the time of posting just showing that the event did fire and return the correct data. sorry about that. glad you got it to work.